# Sharepoint Document Library - How to filter by the "Name" Column

Tags: sharepoint-online

How do I filter by the default Name column in a SharePoint (online) document library? For this column type, there is no "filter by" option in the header.

We have a large library and the users need to quickly navigate to a folder, the best option would be to use the "filter by".

I did add the "title" column which does work, the issue I have with that is that I have to maintain that column so it matches the value in the name field via a flow. Seems like a good bit of overhead for a large list.

Any suggestions on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a *pre-selected filter* for users (i.e. we already know what the users want to filter by), we can create separate views and filter them accordingly.

Example below showing filtering only .docx files on the `Name` column

[image]

If it is a *"dynamic" filter* (i.e. users filter by themselves), then the best way is probably just to use the **Search Box** on top.

[image]

Comment: Thanks thebernardlim. I did create 26 filters to organize by A to Z. That does help.  I also added in the "Name (for use in forms)" column and I can filter by. The problem is there is no option to search the filters in the filter pane :(. There always seems to be a blocker.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the view. Instead of using the column "Name (linked to document with edit menu)", use "Name (for use in forms)".